# Returning an array[] from AsyncTask back to Main Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to return an array from my AsyncTask back to my Activity as I am trying to create a ListView from that array.
Unfortunately, the program bounds error because it wouldn't let me return an array. My codes are as below:

MainMenu Class:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
String username;
public String[] returnValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    username ="user1";  

if (checkInternetConnection()) {

    try {
        MainAsyncTask mat = new MainAsyncTask(MainMenu.this);
        mat.execute(username);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection. Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}}
```

MainAsyncTask:

```
public class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private MainMenu main;
    private String responseText, http;
    private Ipaddress ipaddr = new Ipaddress(http);
    private Context context;

    public MainAsyncTask(MainMenu main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        int responseCode = 0;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(main.getApplicationContext());
            Log.e("SE3", ipaddr.getIpAddress());
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ipaddr.getIpAddress()
                    + "/MainServlet");

            List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("username", arg0[0]);

            Log.e("SE3", arg0[0]);

            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json.toString()));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            if (response != null) {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                        .getContent()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                        responseText = sb.toString();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("SE3", "IO Exception in reading from stream.");
                        responseText = "Error";
                    }
                } else {
                    responseText = "Error";
                }
            } else {
                responseText = "Response is null";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseCode = 408;
            responseText = "Response is null";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseCode;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (result == 408 || responseText.equals("Error")
                || responseText.equals("Response is null")) {
            Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                    "An error has occured, please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            JSONObject jObj;
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(responseText);
                String folderString = jObj.getString("folder");

                String [] folders = folderString.split(";");    
                //I need to return folders back to MainMenu Activity
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how I am supposed to modify so that I am able to read my Array back on my activity with my connections remains intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you declare your `MainAsyncTask` like this:

```
public class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
```

Then modify `doInBackground` to do all the processing that you are now doing in `onPostExecute` (except for the `Toast` part) and have it return the `String[]` (or `null` if there's an error). You can store the result code in an instance variable of `MainAsyncTask` and return `null` on error. Then `onPostExecute` has access to the same info that it does with your current code. Finally, if there is no error, just call a method in your main activity from `onPostExecute` to do the UI updates, passing it the `String[]` result.